# SpecFlow transition between steps takes too much time

Tags: c#, selenium, ui-automation, specflow

We use SpecFlow and Selenium to check that some popup is shown with some expected text.

The problem is that verification contains verification of visibility and content of popup. **But** the popup is shown for 5 seconds(this time can't be increased because it's hardcoded) and transition between steps in SpecFlow takes so much time that when it reaches verification of popup's visibility the popup already disappeared.

Has anybody faced with similar problem? Are there any ways to improve performance of SpecFlow in this case: cache, custom generator or something else? Or maybe we can fix it from Selenium side?

*Notes:*

1. On our CI server we have no such issue
2. We use *Scoped bindings* basically with *Tag*-option
3. We can't divide verification of visibility and content into different steps because it's very frequent use-case in our scenarios
4. Version of SpecFlow is 1.9.0, NUnit - 2.6.4, SpecFlow.NUnit - 1.1.1, Selenium - 2.53.1

Comment: What do you mean by transition? Specflow works as normal as your C# code. It just takes some Millie seconds to go the step definition. I have also worked on same scenario but I never had any issue unless you are debugging the code.

Answer (score 0):

We (SpecFlow Team) are not aware that the transition between steps take so much time. I use SpecFlow on a daily basis and I do not have these effects.

So it has probably something to do with your setup.

- Do you have some [BeforeStep]/[AfterStep] hooks that are executed for every step?
- Is your Selenium query to slow on your local machines?

I would suggest that you open an issue on https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow about it. There we could also easier share detail infos and files.

Comment: I'm not aware about BeforeStep/AfetStep hooks. As I know we use TransformationBindings but I'm sure that during the problem scenario there aren't any transformations to be performed.
Yeah, transitions are slow on our local machines. But we have very good hardware so I don't think that the issue is caused by it.
Anyway, thank you for answer. After second check our dev-team contact you on GitHub if we still get this porblem